# Deploying PlatformCachePartition Metadata - Tests Fail

Tags: deployment, platform-cache

I noticed a strange behaviour when deploying `PlatformCachePartition` metadata which also includes test methods in the same package. Below is an example of the `PlatformCachePartition` metadata:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlatformCachePartition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <isDefaultPartition>true</isDefaultPartition>
    <masterLabel>PlatformCache</masterLabel>
    <platformCachePartitionTypes>
        <allocatedCapacity>10</allocatedCapacity>
        <allocatedPurchasedCapacity>0</allocatedPurchasedCapacity>
        <allocatedTrialCapacity>0</allocatedTrialCapacity>
        <cacheType>Organization</cacheType>
    </platformCachePartitionTypes>
    <platformCachePartitionTypes>
        <allocatedCapacity>10</allocatedCapacity>
        <allocatedPurchasedCapacity>0</allocatedPurchasedCapacity>
        <allocatedTrialCapacity>0</allocatedTrialCapacity>
        <cacheType>Session</cacheType>
    </platformCachePartitionTypes>
</PlatformCachePartition>
```

Tests are pretty simple, we've wrapped all the cache business in another class, but in a nutshell the tests are storing and retrieving a value for a specific key, then asserting:

```
@isTest
public class CacheManager_Test
{
    public static testMethod void testSessionCache() 
    {
        String cacheKey1 = CacheManager.normaliseCacheKey(CacheManager.CacheKey.MY_ENUM);
        CacheManager.putSessionValue(cacheKey1, 'mysamplevalue', 300);
        System.assertEquals('mysamplevalue', CacheManager.getSessionValue(cacheKey1));
    }

    public static testMethod void testOrgCache() 
    {
        String cacheKey1 = CacheManager.normaliseCacheKey(CacheManager.CacheKey.MY_ENUM);
        CacheManager.putOrgValue(cacheKey1, '123', 300);
        System.assertEquals('123', CacheManager.getOrgValue(cacheKey1));
    }
}
```

What's interesting is that when I run these test methods in isolation, they both pass. Even if I deploy the test class into another org it runs, no issues. However, if I also add the `PlatformCachePartition` metadata in the same package and try to deploy (with running tests), both asserts fail. What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After careful investigation, we discovered a couple of things:

- First, this issue seems to be resolved in API `v41.0` (we were using `v40.0` for the deployment for some reason).
- What happens in API's < `v41.0` is that upon deploying `PlatformCachePartition`, the `allocatedCapacity` gets reset to **0**, therefore you can't access the cache. If you must use an older version, you should first deploy and configure the cache allocations in the destination org prior deploying any tests related to the cache, and exclude the `PlatformCachePartition` from the second deployment.